# Converting a list of tuples by combining neighbored elements and cutting the length of the elements

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of tuples, in even length *x*:

```
[(a1,a2,a3,a4),(b1,b2,b3,b4),(c1,c2,c3,c4),(d1,d2,d3,d4), ... ,(x1,x2,x3,x4)]
```

I wish to create a new list of tuples as following:

```
[(a1,a2,b1,b2),(c1,c2,d1,d2),(e1,e2,f1,f2), ... ,((x-1)1,(x-1)2,x1,x2)]
```

As you can see, all the third and fourth elements of the sublists are gone and neighbored sublists have been merged.

I can do it with few loops, but I'm looking for the elegant Python'ish way to do it.

Comment: did you by any chance try something yourself?

Comment: What happens to `[(a3,a4), (b3,b4), ...]`?

Comment: I think the question is now clear enough (also demonstrated by three answers who seem to have understood it right) and can be reopened.

Comment: @Trilarion, I voted to close as it was too broad and the fact the OP supplied  no code showing any effort did not help either

Answer (score 3):

I pondered on the question of *what is the Pythonic way*, and came to the conclusion that *if you do not need a sequence, then accept any iterator* would be the Pythonic one. Martijn's xrange method is not the most pythonic in this sense, and indeed the Martijn's grouper method

```
result = [ i[:2] + j[:2] for i, j in izip(*[iter(l)] * 2) ]
```

is the most pythonic in that it accepts any kind of iterable.

The `[iter(l)] * 2` makes a 2-sized list with the **same** iterator in both elements. The reason why this is faster than my attempt with `next` above, though I didn't think so before, is that the call to `next()` is costly (all function calls and attribute/name resolves are slow on CPython relative to use of inline operators and construction of tuples).

---

This is the quick obvious solution, that I find the most Pythonic with strictly lists:

```
l = [('a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4'), ('b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4'), ('c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4'), ('d1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4')]
y = [ i[:2] + j[:2] for i, j in zip(l[::2], l[1::2]) ]
print y
```

which prints

```
[('a1', 'a2', 'b1', 'b2'), ('c1', 'c2', 'd1', 'd2')]
```

However it is not the most efficient, as `zip` and the slices will create temporary lists on Python 2, thus to speed this up, one can use the `itertools.izip` with `islice` to make a generative solution.

---

But, actually one can abuse an iterator here to make quite **efficient** code, albeit not very Pythonic

```
i = iter(l)
n = i.next
result = [ j[:2] + n()[:2] for j in i ]
print result
```

prints

```
[('a1', 'a2', 'b1', 'b2'), ('c1', 'c2', 'd1', 'd2')]
```

The `for` in list comprehension implicitly calls `next()` on the iterator `i` and assigns the result to `j`; within the list comprehension body we explicitly advance the same iterator to get the next tuple. Then with tuple slicing we take the 2 first elements of the even numbered tuple (0-based) and concatenate the 2 first elements of the next tuple to it. This code however will result in `StopIteration` exception if the number of elements in the original list is not even, unlike the slice'n'zip solutions which would just silently discard the last odd tuple.

Comment: It must be noted that in Python 2, this creates 2 new list objects; the two slices and the `zip()` return value, and discards all three again. That's not as efficient as it could be.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Probably because it's a code only answer

Comment: @DarrickHerwehe: hrm, bit harsh right after posting though.

Answer (score 2):

[Iterate over the list in pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks) and produce new tuples:

```
[tups[i][:2] + tups[i + 1][:2] for i in xrange(0, len(tups), 2)]
```

where `tups` is your input list; use `range()` if you are using Python 3.

If `tups` is an iterable and not a sequence (so if you cannot use indexing for fast access), you can also use the `itertools` `grouper` recipe (adjusted for your usecase and adapted to work on Python 2 and 3):

```
try:
    # Python 2
    from future_builtins import zip
except ImportError:
    pass  # Python 3

def grouper(iterable, n):
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip(*args)

[t1[:2] + t2[:2] for t1, t2 in grouper(tups, 2)]
```

but this somewhat overkill if `tups` is a list.

Demo:

```
>>> tups = [('a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4'), ('b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4'), ('c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4'), ('d1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4')]  
>>> [tups[i][:2] + tups[i + 1][:2] for i in xrange(0, len(tups), 2)]
[('a1', 'a2', 'b1', 'b2'), ('c1', 'c2', 'd1', 'd2')]
```

Even so, the `grouper` option is the faster choice (which surprised me a little):

```
In [1]: tups = [('a', 'a', 'a', 'a')] * 1000

In [2]: from future_builtins import zip

In [3]: def grouper(iterable, n):
   ...:         args = [iter(iterable)] * n
   ...:         return zip(*args)
   ...: 

In [4]: %timeit [tups[i][:2] + tups[i + 1][:2] for i in xrange(0, len(tups), 2)]
10000 loops, best of 3: 112 µs per loop

In [5]: %timeit [t1[:2] + t2[:2] for t1, t2 in grouper(tups, 2)]
10000 loops, best of 3: 90.6 µs per loop
```

Comment: I don't like the `for i in xrange(...len(tups)...)`.  I'd rather use something like `for tup1, tup2 in zip(tups[::2], tups[1::2])`

Comment: @Kevin: which creates *new list objects*.

Comment: Then use `itertools.islice()`.

Comment: @Kevin: you may as well use the `itertools` *`grouper()`* recipe in that case (see the linked question I link to from my answer). But the `xrange()` option is just as faster if the input is a sequence. `itertools` is wonderful if the input is an iterable instead.